# Recovering from git push -f

Tags: git, github

I am totally new to programming and I'm using GIT first time.

I am trying to build Ruby web app and I had problems to git push and somebody told me to use git push -f. But now I read that it was probably really bad thing to do. Now when I try to git push I get this message from command line:

"You are not currently on a branch.
To push the history leading to the current (detached HEAD)
state now, use

git push origin HEAD:"

How should I try to recover from this?

Thank you!

Comment: "and somebody told me to use git push -f" --- lol, next time you will think and read before you run some random commands

Comment: What command you used to push??? Because this error has nothing to do with the force push you did before.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I am saying, the error doesn't match the force push.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `git reflog` to check if you have any previous commit that the remotes/origin/master points to.